# Sweetalert2 : correct way to completely disable animation with version >= 9.0.0

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

Before version **9.0.0** i used this code to completely disable animation on a **toast** alert.

```
Swal.fire({
    animation : false,
    toast: true,
    ....
});
```

Now with version 9.* i tried with this code, and the result it looks the same

```
Swal.fire({
    showClass : { popup : "swal2-noanimation", backdrop : "swal2-noanimation", icon : "swal2-noanimation"},
    //hideClass : { popup : "swal2-noanimation", backdrop : "swal2-noanimation", icon : "swal2-noanimation"},
    toast: true,
    ....
});
```

If i enable also the property **hideClass** i can't hide the alert with the method **Swal.close()**.

So what is the correct solution to get the same effect as before?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting from [`v11.10.0`](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v11.10.0) the `animation` parameter was re-introduced:

```js
Swal.fire({
  ...
  animation: false
})
```

---

⚠ OUTDATED ANSWER BELOW: ⚠

As per deprection message:

> SweetAlert2: "animation" is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release. Please use "**showClass**" and "**hideClass**" instead.

```js
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'success',
  title: 'I am not animated',
  showClass: {
    backdrop: 'swal2-noanimation', // disable backdrop animation
    popup: '',                     // disable popup animation
    icon: ''                       // disable icon animation
  },
  hideClass: {
    popup: '',                     // disable popup fade-out animation
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Read the release notes to see all breaking changes: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v9.0.0

Comment: Nooooooo !!! I had read the whole release note, but i had not noticed that line where it is explained how to get the same result of animation : false :(
Sorry and thank you!